# Does IGN affect downloaded modules from occurring?

Tags: apt, compiling, gcc

```
sudo apt-get update
```

After inputting that command, the following occurs:

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

For all the modules, all of them say IGN and it repeats over and over with the same modules attempted to be downloaded until a formal error occurs. "Temporary failure resolving" . For context, I have recently downloaded Ubuntu to test C on it via downloading GCC, but when I attempt to download gcc, it's more modules so the same error as previously stated occurs. If I am right and essentially no modules have been downloaded due to the ignore, is there a work-around/fix for this specific issue?

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

```
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
ping: www.ubuntu.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=118 time=70.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=118 time=63.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=118 time=65.4 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 63.585/66.441/70.310/2.837 ms
```

Per instructions:

```
ls -al /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Feb  1 18:12 /etc/resolv.conf -> /mnt/wsl/resolv.conf
```

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

Comment: Were you actually connected to the internet at the time? Please post: `ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com` and: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chii555 I attached the code-fences to my actual post because I think you may be right. My connection to Ubuntu is faulty which results in constant "IGN's", but I am connected to the Internet.

Comment: Please add: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` We're getting closer.

Comment: @chili555 The weirdest thing is when I sudo nano /etc/resolve.conf it shows my name server, but doesn't let me restart.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know this is a WSL installation. I know nothing about WSL.